# como funciona o 'e' do javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em alguns códigos que vejo, algumas pessoas utilizam o caractere 'e' em funções como:

```
function NomeDaFuncao(e){ 
  alert("teste");
}
```

gostaria de saber como funciona, para que serve e algum exemplo onde eu possa usá-lo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O uso é apenas um curto event. Você pode passar qualquer nome de variável que você deseja.

```
$('#myTable').click(function(anyothername) {
    var clicked = $(anyothername.target);
});
```

Você pode verificar mais sobre o [tratamento dos eventos da jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/working-with-jquery-13-new-event-object.html) .